# C# new keyword to override access modifier on a property from a 3rd party lib

Tags: c#

I'm using a 3rd party lib with the following class:

```
 class Base {
    protected int Count { get; }
 }
```

I inherit from this class in my code, however, I would like Count to be a public property. Is the following considered bad in any way? Are there other ways to do it?

```
 class Derived : Base {
    public new int Count { get { return base.Count; } }
 }
```

Comment: Just don't, give it a different name.

Comment: @HansPassant Why? Makes the API more complicated with now 2 different properties referring to the same thing. Can you think of any benefit from doing this?

Comment: Because somebody is going to lose an hour of his life on a mystifying error message for no good reason.  If you don't care about that then just do your own thing.

Comment: @HansPassant What error message? There is none, seems to be a valid use of language features.

Comment: I guess he means `Base b = new Derived(); b.Count;` However, any reason why `Count` is `protected`?

Comment: @JesseGood Ok, in that case I agree to change it. Here's the error: http://ideone.com/wiENwm . Not exactly mystifying, says exactly what the problem is, but valid enough to not use this.

Comment: Although come to think of it, this error is expected because Count is protected on the Base class.

Comment: I agree with @HansPassant. The problem is your Count may look like an override of the base Count, but it's very different. Rather than hide that fact, better to highlight it (lampshade it) by giving it a distinctive name, maybe `ExposedCount`, or something like that. Good luck.